# Make data in spreadsheet as credentials for login form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a login and register form website created via AppScript.

In my website I have 2 textbox & 1 button for my register form and same for my login form.

Once you register the values you input will be stored in my spreadsheet

[image: here's the outcome]

The problem is, when I try to log-in using the same value in my spreadsheet I recieve an error. Here's the error :

[image]

I don't know where's the error in my code. I have two separate codes, 1 in the funcs.gs and 1 in my Html form.

Here's the code in the funcs.gs

```
function getRegister(userInfo1){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Credentials");

  ws.appendRow([userInfo1.name,userInfo1.pass,new Date()]);

}

function getCredentials(creds){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Credentials");
    var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
    Logger.log(data);
}
```

The function getCredentials(creds) can fetch the data in my spreadsheet

Here's the sample log :

[image]

But apparently I can't use the values in the spreadsheet as a login credentials.

Can someone tell me what's the problem with my code? All suggestions are very much appreciated. (Working or not, still you tried to help someone in need)

And Here's the code in my loginlogin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600|Montserrat:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700|Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
  </head>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  })

</script>
<body>
  <div id="myForm" class="container1">
    <a class="waves-effect btn waves-effect waves-red btn red lighten- modal-trigger" href="#demo-modal1">Register</a>
    <a class="waves-effect btn waves-effect waves-red btn red lighten- modal-trigger" href="#demo-modal2">Login</a>
  </div>
<div id="demo-modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 style="color:blue;">Register Form</h4>
      <div class="container">
      <input id="name" type="text" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="pass" type="password">
      <button id="btn" onClick="addRecord()" type="submit">Register</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="demo-modal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 style="color:blue;">Login Form</h4>
      <div class="container">
      <input id="uname" type="text" autocomplete="off">
      <input id="upass" type="password">
      <button id="btn1" onClick="check_form()" type="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </body>


</html>
<style>
.container1{
 margin-left: 40%;
 margin-right: 40%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}
</style>
<script>

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes);

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler.getCredentials();

  });

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",addRecord);

      function addRecord(){

      var userInfo1 = {};

      userInfo1.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      userInfo1.pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;


      if(!checkEmptyInput()){
      google.script.run.getRegister(userInfo1);

      document.getElementById("name").value = "";
      document.getElementById("pass").value = "";

    }
   }

    function checkEmptyInput() {
       var isEmpty = false,
           name = document.getElementById("name").value,
           passowrd = document.getElementById("pass").value;

       if(name === ""){
           alert("Fields are all required");
           isEmpty = true;
       }
       else if(passowrd === ""){
           alert("Fields are all required");
           isEmpty = true;
       }
       else{
        alert("Registration Sucess!");
       }
        return isEmpty;
       }

var match = google.script.run.getCredentials();
var login_attempts=3;
function check_form() {


 var name = document.getElementById("uname").value;
 var pass = document.getElementById("upass").value;
 var match = google.script.run.getCredentials();

 if(name== match   && pass== match )
 {
  alert("SuccessFully Logged In");
  document.getElementById("uname").value="";
  document.getElementById("upass").value="";
  window.top.location.replace("https://script.google.com/a/taskus.com/macros/s/AKfycbw_mzCq816eQXk0yQ2tz626b1BXXrQq63erTJUBTnk_/dev?v=manuel");
 }

else
 {
  if(login_attempts==0)
  {
   alert("No Login Attempts Available");
  }
  else
  {
   login_attempts=login_attempts-1;
   alert("Login Failed Now Only "+login_attempts+" Login Attempts Available");
   if(login_attempts==0)
   {
    document.getElementById("uname").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("upass").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("myForm").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("btn1").disabled=true;
   }
  }
 }

 return false;
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Wait... you're storing passwords in plain text? Oh boy.

Comment: It's just for a test. I'll change it once the login works

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I don't have the answer. But this looks pretty funky to me:

```
var name = document.getElementById("uname").value;
 var pass = document.getElementById("upass").value;
 var match = google.script.run.getCredentials();

 if(name== match   && pass== match ) {
 ....
}
```

1) You are checking if name and password are both equal to match. This is the condition that must be met to allow login.

2) Match appears to be a function that doesn't do anything apart from set three variables and then log one of them (data):

function getCredentials(creds){

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Credentials");
var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();
Logger.log(data);
```

}

I would start by logging what is returned by match, and fix that so you are getting username and password. And split this function to check for username and password separately. From what is currently returned, it looks like you'd need to drill down into the array like:

```
match[1][0] // Username
match[1][1] // Password
```

Comment: Do you have wny sample codes? It's a bit hard to understand cause I'm just a beginner in coding. Thank you so much

Comment: Start by logging what is returned by match, and post the results here. That's your first clue :) var match = google.script.run.getCredentials(); Logger.log(match)

Comment: Alright, I'll do it tomorrow morning when I comr back to work. It's been a rough day and I need to rest but anyway, thank you so much for the tips! I'll send the result tomorrow evening. Goodnight

Comment: Hi, I tried following your instructions and apparently I can't run the Logger.log (match) since it's coded in thr html and not in the code.gs.

Comment: In the js file in your html, straight after you run var match = google.script.run.getCredentials(); run console.log(match). You'll see what is returned -this is what you are trying to validate against.

Comment: Have you tried it on my code? Does it works? But yea, I'll let you know what's the result. Thank you :)

Comment: It's not working. I'm really depressed, I don't know in what way can I do it. :(

Comment: When you say 'it's not working', what do you mean exactly? Don't be depressed, this stuff is especially hard at the start, and the more problems you encounter the better you'll get. Break your code down line by line, try to understand what each line does. It's hard to debug without a working live example but the main issue I see is that you are not comparing the stored password/username with the user input. So you need to get these to match. What is the result of console.log(match)?

Comment: I can't see the logs on that google.script.run.getCredentials on my html page. I can only run that function on the gs page. :( I can't do it. Please help me :(

Comment: In between these two lines on your html js file: var match = google.script.run.getCredentials();

 if(name== match   && pass== match ) you need to run console.log(match)

Comment: Ok i'll try it one more time :( thankyou for keeping on giving me eays to solvr my problem. Sorry for being a burden at the same time :(